# Beautiful Soup 4 isn't pulling down all the html on this web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So, i'm trying to learn how to do web scraping with python, and to do this, i want to figure out how to scrape all of the audio files off of [this website](https://www.nasa.gov/connect/sounds/index.html).

So, here's my current code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nasa.gov/connect/sounds/index.html').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

However, i don't think it's pulling down all of the HTML from the page, as this is the output i get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/ dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/ og: http://ogp.me/ns# rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns# sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types# skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core# xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
<head>
<meta content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="NASA" property="og:site_name"/>
<link href="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab" rel="profile"/>
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
<meta content="text/html" name="dc.format"/>
<meta content="Text" name="dc.type"/>
<meta content="und" name="dc.language"/>
<meta content="/connect/sounds/index.html" name="dc.identifier"/>
<meta content="2015-01-26T09:44-05:00" name="dc.date"/>
<meta content="Jim Wilson" name="dc.creator"/>
<meta content="Audio and Ringtones" name="dc.title"/>
<meta content="/connect/sounds/index.html" property="twitter:url"/>
<meta content="11348282" property="twitter:site:id"/>
<meta content="@NASA" property="twitter:site"/>
<meta content="article" property="og:type"/>
<link href="/connect/sounds/index.html" rel="shortlink"/>
<meta content="NASA.gov brings you the latest images, videos and news from America's space agency. Get the latest updates on NASA missions, watch NASA TV live, and learn about our quest to reveal the unknown and benefit all humankind." name="description"/>
<meta content="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/potw1335a_0.jpg" property="twitter:image1"/>
<meta content="NASA.gov brings you the latest images, videos and news from America's space agency. Get the latest updates on NASA missions, watch NASA TV live, and learn about our quest to reveal the unknown and benefit all humankind." property="og:description"/>
<meta content="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/nasa_insignia_300.jpg" property="og:image"/>
<meta content="gallery" property="twitter:card"/>
<meta content="NASA brings you images, videos and features from the unique perspective of America's space agency. Get updates on missions, watch NASA TV, read blogs, view the latest discoveries, and 
more." property="twitter:description"/>
<meta content="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/astro.jpg" property="twitter:image0"/>
<meta content="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/earth_1000.jpg" property="twitter:image2"/>
<link href="/connect/sounds/index.html" rel="canonical"/>
<meta content="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/Aeroplane.jpeg" property="twitter:image3"/>
<meta content="Audio and Ringtones" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="http://www.nasa.gov/connect/sounds/index.html" property="og:url"/>
<meta content="Audio and Ringtones" property="twitter:title"/>
<meta content="http://www.nasa.gov" property="twitter:image"/>
<meta content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" name="generator"/>
<script type="application/ld+json">{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "WebPage",
            "@id": "https://www.nasa.gov/connect/sounds/index.html",
            "name": "Audio and Ringtones",
            "description": "NASA.gov brings you the latest images, videos and news from America\u0027s space agency. Get the latest updates on NASA missions, watch NASA TV live, and learn about our quest to reveal the unknown and benefit all humankind.",
            "author": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "@id": "https://www.nasa.gov/connect/sounds/index.html",
                "name": "NASA",
                "url": "https://www.nasa.gov",
                "sameAs": [
                    "https://twitter.com/nasa",
                    "https://www.facebook.com/nasa",
                    "https://instagram.com/nasa",
                    "https://plus.google.com/+NASA"
                ]
            },
            "publisher": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "@id": "https://www.nasa.gov/connect/sounds/index.html",
                "name": "NASA",
                "url": "https://www.nasa.gov",
                "sameAs": "https://twitter.com/nasa,https://www.facebook.com/nasa,https://instagram.com/nasa,https://plus.google.com/+NASA",
                "logo": {
                    "@type": "ImageObject",
                    "url": "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/nasa-logo.svg",
                    "width": "110",
                    "height": "92"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "WebSite",
            "@id": "www.nasa.gov",
            "name": "NASA",
            "url": "www.nasa.gov"
        }
    ]
}</script>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0" name="viewport"/>
<title>Audio and Ringtones | NASA</title>
<meta content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22nasa%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22baseURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyHeader%22%3A%22Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%27none%27%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27unsafe-eval%27%22%2C%22font-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22img-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22style-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22media-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%7D%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Atrue%7D" name="nasa/config/environment"/>
<link href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
<link href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76"/>
<link href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120"/>
<link href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152"/>
<style>
@import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_before_after_image/scald_before_after_image.css?");
@import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_htmlsnippet/scald_htmlsnippet.css?");
@import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_iframe/scald_iframe.css?");
</style>
<link href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/css/vendor.css?" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/css/nasa.css?" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script id="_fed_an_ua_tag" language="javascript" src="https://dap.digitalgov.gov/Universal-Federated-Analytics-Min.js?agency=NASA&amp;yt=true&amp;dclink=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE *****************************************
    ;(function (g) {
      var d = document, am = d.createElement('script'), h = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0], fsr = 'fsReady',
        aex = {
          "src": "//gateway.answerscloud.com/nasa-gov/production/gateway.min.js",
          "type": "text/javascript",
          "async": "true",
          "data-vendor": "fs",
          "data-role": "gateway"
        };
      for (var attr in aex){am.setAttribute(attr, aex[attr]);}h.appendChild(am);g[fsr] = function () {var aT = '__' + fsr + '_stk__';g[aT] = g[aT] || [];g[aT].push(arguments);};
    })(window);
    // DO NOT MODIFY ABOVE THIS LINE *****************************************
    </script>
<script>window.landingPageID = 336285</script>
<script>window.Drupal = {behaviors: {}};</script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/js/vendor.js?"></script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/js/nasa.js?"></script>
</head>
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in page-node page-node- page-node-336285 node-type-landing-page-2015 section-connect">
<div class="l-page ember-init-hide">
<header class="l-header container-fluid" role="banner"></header>
<div class="l-main">
<div class="l-content container-fluid" id="main" role="main">
<script>
window.forcedRoute = "landingPage";
window.cardFeed = [];
</script>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="l-footer container-fluid" role="contentinfo">
<script async="async" src="//script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0070/1109.js"></script>
</footer>
</div>
<script>
      /**
       * Â© 2011-2014 iPerceptions, Inc. All rights reserved. Do not distribute.
       * iPerceptions provides this code 'as is' without warranty of any kind,
       * either express or implied.
       */

     window.iperceptionskey = 'CTS00001';
     (function () {
       var a = document.createElement('script'),
           b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       a.type = 'text/javascript';
       a.async = true;
       a.src = '//universal.iperceptions.com/wrapper.js';b.appendChild(a);
     })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, as you can see, the hyperlinks that contain the download files for the audio links does not appear at all. And when you go to the webpage, you can inspect the webpage and see that it's not pulling all of it down. Any ideas on why this might be? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you see if you use `View Source` on the website? `requests` and BS don't execute JavaScript, so you won't see dynamic content loaded using AJAX.

Comment: You need to use something like Selenium WebDriver to emulate a browser.

Comment: @Barmar I see, i didn't even realize it was being generated by javascript. Any reason you can think of why they would do hyperlinks like that, rather than just regular HTML? Thanks

Comment: Probably because it's being generated dynamically from a database.

Comment: @Barmar I see, well i appreciate you pointing me in the proper direction!

Comment: Also, @Barmar, how could you tell it's AJAX generated? I was poking through it and couldn't find any reference to AJAX.

Comment: What else could it be? If the data isn't in the source, it has to be fetched dynamically.

Comment: Use the Network tab in the browser to see what it's fetching. There are several `.json` files being downloaded, e.g. main-menu.json that contains the menus in the header.

Comment: I see references to Drupal, which is a Content Management System.

Comment: @Barmar, i'm not really sure, i'm just trying to understand how it's being generated the best that i can, and i couldn't really figure it out how AJAX was being called when i was going through the HTML. And i didn't know if there were other methods to dynamically fetch stuff besides AJAX

Comment: AJAX is the term we use for dynamically fetching data from the server.

Comment: It's loading lots of other JS libraries, so you won't see the AJAX calls in the main HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments by others, the page is rendered dynamically. But hey, if you don't look for reliability (as in "i just wanna grab the stuff now and don't mind all that much if my script breaks very soon"), you can just look at the traffic...

After a quick look you realize the actual html body you seem to be trying to get seems to be wrapped in a json, specifically, in https://www.nasa.gov/api/1/record/node/336285.json

Knowing this, picking it up in a quick and dirty way, and regexing the mp3 links out of it, is pretty damn simple:

```
import requests, json, re

source = requests.get('https://www.nasa.gov/api/1/record/node/336285.json')
j = json.loads(source.content.decode())
body = j['landingPage']['body']

for mp3 in re.findall(r"http.*?\.mp3", body):
    print(mp3)
```

The code below is pretty much the same, but will also download all the mp3s:

```
import requests, json, re, html, string

source = requests.get('https://www.nasa.gov/api/1/record/node/336285.json')
j = json.loads(source.content.decode())
body = j['landingPage']['body']

for mp3 in re.findall(r"(http.*?\.mp3).*?\>(.*?)\<", body):
    link = mp3[0]
    title = html.unescape(mp3[1])
    filename = ''.join(c for c in title if c in "-_.() %s%s" % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits)) + ".mp3"
    print("Downloading %s..." % filename)
    with open(filename, "wb") as target:
        target.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I'll definitly be disecting this to try and understand it tommorow! This is fantastic!